# Creating WooCommerce Custom API

Tags: php, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm looking into creating a WooCommerce endpoint due to the lack of many functionalities in the WooCommerce REST API provided out of the box.

Examples are : Payment, Product-Addons, etc

But I can't find anything to start with, no documentation on how to extend WooCommerce to create a new endpoint. All I could find was creating a Plugin, but I'm not sure if that's what I need.

I want to create php files when called return the desired data like products and orders.

I've tried adding actions and filters to the **functions.php** file, but I can't seem to find the right action/filter for what I want, and looking online I only find old answers that used the old versions of WooCommerce API (legacy v1-2-3 instead of the new v1-2-3).

Comment: Did you come to a solution?

Comment: @kadddeee not much of a solution but a work around. Adding custom endpoints in WordPress to access everything in the database, using WP and WC classes and methods. But when the WP & WC fail, it's back to plain old database access.

Comment: Ooo this sounds to be something similar to what I am trying to achieve,  do you have an example of one end point you created that you can show me please, because I want to have access to the 'Booking' extension I added to Woocommerce which is currently not accessible via the rest api. But I don't know where to start I've been able to make a custom endpoint but how to pull the data I have no idea. Where did you find these classes and methods?

Comment: Also check out my question here @Ahmad maybe you can be of assistance, thank you ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54387226/extending-the-woocommerce-rest-api